# Getting empty dataframe on parsing XML with XSD using spark-xml package

Tags: xml, apache-spark, xsd, apache-spark-xml

I am trying to parse simple XML by supplying XSD schema. Using the approach given here.

https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#xsd-support

XML is here:

```
<note>
  <to>aa</to>
  <from>bb</from>
  <heading>cc</heading>
  <body>dd</body>
</note>
```

XSD is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I am trying to read this XSD and trying to build schema like below.

```
import com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema
import java.nio.file.Paths
val schemaParsed = XSDToSchema.read(Paths.get("<local_linux_path>/sample_file.xsd"))
print(schemaParsed)
```

Here schema successfully parsed. Next I am reading XML file like below.

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").schema(schemaParsed).load("<hdfs_path>/sample_file.xml")
```

After this step I can display schema of Dataframe using df.printSchema() , But content is coming as empty if I am giving df.show()

Please guide me where I am doing wrong here.

Note: This question is exactly same as this: [How to parse XML with XSD using spark-xml package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67281690/how-to-parse-xml-with-xsd-using-spark-xml-package)

But reposting same question again as I am not able to comment there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your XSD element names are incorrect.  You can use tools like this [online XSD / XML validator](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) to pick out the errors.

Do these element names match your schema?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**RowTag**
You may also need to pass in a rowTag to spark to define the tag that marks each row of data:

```
.options(rowTag='note')
```

**Experimental features in use**
According the [this documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml), the XSDToSchema utility is experimental and only works with certain schemas.

Comment: Hey sry, seems like some typo error from my side. I have already checked that names are matching. let me update correct names in question.

Comment: @Keds - I've updated my answer with two other considerations. Hopefully they help.